# Sharepoint-This page contains both secure and nonsecure items" Error with RSS feeds

Tags: sharepoint

I have a shared site in sharepoint and have some RSS feed webpart in it so now everytime my site opens up it shows this popup.

I know I can remove the popup by going to IE options and stuff but my question is if there is any way that i can remove it permanently because I can't tell my users to follow this process but I have lot of complaints because of this popup.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being is the RSS feed is not secure. Try to get the feed to use SSL, instead of http://www.cnn.com/rss, try https://www.cnn.com/rss.

If there is not an SSL port available, request one.

If the users are on a Domain, you can use a group policy that will auto allow that RSS feeds url/site.